# How to resolve the error IndentationError: expected an indented block in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython

See my error in:

```
print('Olá, usuario bem-vindo ao J.A.R.V.I.S')
print('Antes de comecar, deixa-me fazer-te algumas perguntas para te conhecer melhor')
nome = input('Como te chamas?')
idade = input('Qual e a tua idade?')
print('Dados Guardados no banco MYSQL!')
print('Olá,', nome, 'Prazer em conhecer-te!')
print('Antes de continuar deixa-me que me apresente, eu sou o jarvis fui criado por: Tomás Dinis e o meu coração é feito em PYTHON 3.3, sou um robot com inteligencia artificial e faço praticamente tudo o que voce quer!')
pergunta = input('O que queres que eu faca por ti?')
if pergunta == "desligate":
print('adorei!')
```

Please Help !

Comment: What's not clear about it? You need to add some spaces in the front of the last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
if pergunta == "desligate":
print('adorei!')
```

The contents of an `if` block must be indented farther in than the conditional of that block.

```
if pergunta == "desligate":
    print('adorei!')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)